# Транспонирование данных в таблице Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, unpivot

Необходимо транспонировать столбцы в таблице. Важно, что значения названия столбцов (A,B) - это строковые переменные должны стать названиями полученных вертикальных столбцов, а порядковые номера X(1)... порядковым номером строк полученной таблицы.

Исходный DataFrame:

```
   Name/X     X1  X2  X3  X4
    A         10  12  33  31
    B         22  14  44  17
```

Выход должен быть таким:

```
 N   A   B
 1   10  22
 2   12  14
 3   33  44
 4   31  17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала нужно сделать UNPIVOT по столбцам "X*", превратив таблицу из широкой в высокую, а после этого сделать PIVOT, используя наименования "X*" столбцов в качестве индекса, а значения из столбца "Name/X" в качестве наименований будущих столбцов:

```
res = (df
      .set_index("Name/X")
      .stack()
      .reset_index()
      .pivot_table(index="level_1", columns="Name/X", values=0)
      .reset_index(drop=True)
```

результат:

```
In [243]: res
Out[243]:
Name/X   A   B
0       10  22
1       12  14
2       33  44
3       31  17
```

---

> А как сделать в конечной таблице в столбце Name/X сделать не значения
> индекса строк, а порядковый номер строки, который соответствует номеру
> столбца в исходной таблице?

```
res = (df
       .set_index("Name/X")
       .stack()
       .reset_index()
       .pivot_table(index="level_1", columns="Name/X", values=0)
       .rename_axis(None))
res.index = res.index.str.replace(r"^\D+", "", regex=True)
```

результат:

```
In [254]: res
Out[254]:
Name/X   A   B
1       10  22
2       12  14
3       33  44
4       31  17
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать в конечной таблице в столбце Name/X не значения индекса строк, а порядковый номер строки, который соответствует номеру столбца в исходной таблице. Я не особо силен в python, понимаю, что можно сделать "кастыльно" просто прикрепив столбец порядкового номера, вместо Name/X , но как это сделать более правильно с учетом вашего решения? Если слишком запутанно то простыми словами - что бы значения Name/X шли от 1 до 4, т.е. столько же сколько у нас столбцов X в исходной

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4

df1_transposed = df1.T # or df1.transpose()
df1_transposed
      0  1
col1  1  2
col2  3  4
```

Here more detail about transpose
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы (и на принятом здесь русском языке). дополнить и перевести ответ можно, нажав [edit]